# How to click on href link using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, partiallinktext

I am working on a program that automates logs into to a certain webpage and clicks certain buttons & links to reach a final destination to enter certain values and submit them. I have managed to navigate through the webpages but one of the webpages has a hyperlink button that I need Selenium to click, however, after trying multiple different methods, I cannot get it to work.

I have tried finding the element with `By.XPATH`, `By.LINK_TEXT`, `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` and none of these worked. I thought my issue might be that since it is clicking onto a totally new URL, so I load the new URL towards the bottom of my code to then move forward with my program.

The hyperlink button:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKQ9.png)

The chunk of code to the hyperlink button I am trying to click on:

[image: Code containing hyperlink]

The XPath itself is : `/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/span/a[2]`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('')

'''
username_input = '//*[@id="userNameInput"]'
password_input = '//*[@id="passwordInput"]'
submit_button = '//*[@id="submitButton"]'
send_push = '//*[@id="auth_methods"]/fieldset/div[1]/button'
'''

# enters username and password into fields
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="userNameInput"]').click()
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="userNameInput"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="passwordInput"]').click()
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="passwordInput"]').send_keys(password)


driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="submitButton"]').click()

# clicks 'send me a push' button on duo mobile screen
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='duo_iframe']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath", "//button[normalize-space()='Send Me a Push']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath", '//*[@id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_xWhKj4tIFYvm_"]/div/div/div[1]/a[5]'))).click()

# loads next url which has the link on its webpage that needs to be clicked
driver.get('')

# attempts to click on link
driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/span/a[2]').click()
```

I have removed the URLs in `driver.get('')` as they contain sensitive URLs

My last line of code is my attempt to click the hyperlink using the XPath

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

After further investigation, I now see that 2 buttons both have the same class name in their elements:

The SITE MAP button: [SITE MAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoTS0.png)

The Student button: [Student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXXW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `find_element` does not return the correct element hence cannot click. Or you can verify it by changing `.click()` to `.text`. If it returns `SITE MAP`, then it returns a correct element.

I have another solution if you can try. It's using `xpath` and assumes `class='pageheaderlink'` is a single element in the HTML body.

```py
list_subcontent = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='pageheaderlink']")

for item in list_subcontent:
    if item.text == 'SITE MAP':
        item.click()
```

Comment: After trying this method, it did not seem to work. I am understanding your train of thought with searching for 'SITE MAP' with the for loop then clicking. However, I feel my issue might be lying within list_subcontent and the XPATH itself

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML:

[image: element]

The element with text as ***SITE MAP*** is a `<a>` tag and a dynamic element. To click on the ***clickable*** element  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "SITE MAP"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.submenulinktext2"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='submenulinktext2' and contains(., 'SITE MAP')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, after trying all of the possible solutions you've given, none seem to work.

After further investigation on the site, I noticed there is 2 buttons that have the same name within their elements. I have updated the post to show this.

Using CSS_SELECTOR is something I have not seen yet so I appreciate you showing that too. I am wondering if 2 buttons having the same name here have any role in it not being able to click. Not sure if I should use an action chain to click also